# How to set value to element in directive template with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have some directive and some template in it.

```
angular.module('testModule', [])
    .directive('testInput', function () {
        var id = 1;
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                model: '='
            },
            template: '<div><input type="text" id="{{uniqueId}}"/></div>',
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.uniqueId = "test" + id++;

                $('#' + scope.uniqueId).val(33);
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to set value to element with uniqueId, but I can't do it.
Can you help me?
There is example on Plunker: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/y0pdmEZvRpDN2LzkLDsB?p=preview).
Thanks.

Edit.

I find another solution.

```
        .......
 template: '<div><input type="text" id="{{uniqueId}}" ng-value="someModel"/></div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.uniqueId = "test" + id++;
            scope.someModel = 887;
        }
        .......
```

Example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AqxjaQ5zlNTDI0woduti?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery unfortunately goes outside angular's `$digest` cycle. The easier way is using what the `link` function normally provides, which is access to three variables `scope`, `elem` and `attrs` so you could go about doing something like this:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.uniqueId = "test" + id++;
        elem.children().first()[0].value = 33;
    }
```

Here's a fork of your plunk that works

http://plnkr.co/edit/j1bheHFhkKobb2bWPeRQ?p=preview

Comment: Glad to help my friend